# programmatically set Paypal purchase 'value'

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, paypal

I'm trying to build my first paypal shopping payment system. Paypal helpfully provide some base code to aid with this:

```
<div id="paypal-button-container"></div>
<script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=[MY-CLIENT-ID]&currency=GBP" data-sdk-integration-source="button-factory"></script>
<script>
  paypal.Buttons({
      style: {
          shape: 'rect',
          color: 'white',
          layout: 'vertical',
          label: 'paypal',

      },
      createOrder: function(data, actions) {
          return actions.order.create({
              purchase_units: [{
                  amount: {
                      value: '1'
                  }
              }]
          });
      },
      onApprove: function(data, actions) {
          return actions.order.capture().then(function(details) {
              alert('Transaction completed by ' + details.payer.name.given_name + '!');
          });
      }
  }).render('#paypal-button-container');
</script>
```

I can't seem to figure out how to set the 'value' label inside the function inside of:

```
createOrder: function(data, actions) {
          return actions.order.create({
              purchase_units: [{
                  amount: {
                      value: '1'
                  }
              }]
          });
```

My website is in bootstrap 4.5 with jQuery. On the site's index.html page I have 2 buttons that can be clicked to purchase two different services. Depending on which one the user selects, I use javascript to set the value in `localStorage` as follows: `localStorage.setItem('serviceCost', $('#standard-cost').text());` This grabs a value from a span tag with ID 'standard-cost'. This is then used to set the text on the purchase.html page confirming for the user their selected item. I want to get the value from `localStorage.getItem(serviceCost)` and use it to set the cost for the 'value' key in the above function but everything I attempt is unsuccessful. The paypal script is embedded in a html page and the jQuery is in a separate file. The Paypal site doesn't offer any insight into this and I'm assuming this is a fairly common process, so how do you get a value from `localStorage` and pass it to the `value` variable in Paypal's generated code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
              amount: {
                  value: localStorage.getItem('serviceCost')
              }
```

Yep

Comment: Missed the quote marks. Could kick myself. Thanks for your help! :)